# Deployment of Azure Function with Shared Assemblies

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm building a Azure Function for which I use a kind of precompiled approach. In the function itself we only have one call "Process.Run()" that starts a precompiled private DLL. Those dll's are saved in a Shared folder on the root of the web application.

Everything is running perfectly for as far as we can see but now we would like to deploy this via ARM templates or PowerShell scripts (ZIP). We also use the Visual Studio Preview Function Template.

The form in which we would like to deploy is

```
-- Host
---Shared (Deploy DLL's in this folder)
---HttpTriggerFunctionCSharep1
----(Deploy the needed files to this directory)
```

Comment: Are you using VSTS to deploy this ARM template?

Comment: Not at the moment, but it has to be a completly scripted deployment

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which you can deploy an Azure Function. [Here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/09/04/azure-functions-deployment-strategies/) is a nice blogpost about it and I will summarize it for you below and added the fourth point.

1. GIT integration
2. KUDU Rest API
3. MSdeploy.exe / WAWSDeploy.exe
4. ARM template in combination with MSDeploy.

My preferred method is #4. You need to do several steps for this deployment.

1. Create a ZIP containing the code for the Azure Function App. The content in the ZIP needs to have the [correct folder structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#folder-structure).
2. Upload this ZIP to a Azure Storage blob container.
3. In your ARM template deploy an empty function app ([This one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-function-app-create-dynamic) can be your starting point.)
4. Add a MSDeploy ARM resource to the Azure Function App to deploy the ZIP to the Function App. This is an example of a MSDeploy resource:

```
{
    "name": "MSDeploy",
    "type": "extensions",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('functionAppName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "packageUri": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccount'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', parameters('storageContainer'), '/', parameters('zipFile'))]",
        "dbType": "None",
        "connectionString": ""
    }
}
```

I also found this example implementation which is also based on the principles I described above: https://github.com/ianalderman/AZF_Samples/tree/master/DeploymentExample.

Comment: Number 4 is the option we are using now. We use a empty web project for the creation of the deployment package and we deploy trough a ARM template. But I was hoping that there would be a better or easier solution.

Comment: I'm not currently aware of a better way. We are also using this approach with the several Functions we have up-and-running.